# How to create DB using Application Express for Oracle Express 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm using Oracle express 10g. Is there a way to create a database using the application express admin page. There are 4 icon menus which are Administration, Object Browser, SQL, and Utilities. None appear to provide the create db or schema option. Is via sqlplus the only way? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using "database" in the Oracle sense?  Assuming you are using Oracle XE, you can only have one database.  That database will be named XE.  It will be created when you install the software.  I'm guessing that you may be talking about creating a "schema"?

Comment: You can create any number of schemas (e.g. there is an option to create a schema when you create a new workspace), but not additional databases.

Comment: Also, XE 10g is an old version - you should really consider upgrading to 11g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

When you installed XE. it automatically creates a database called "XE". 
You can use your login username : system and password that you set to login.